# How do you format floats into strings in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, string, floating-point, format

I am trying to format a float into a string with a set number of digits. All the examples I have seen use something like this:

```
let thisString = String(format: "%2.4f" , 3.14159262)
```

However, when I try this I get:

> Argument labels '(format:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

. Like it doesn't even recognize "format" as a valid way to initialize a string. I am using Swift 5 on Xcode 10.2 on Mojave, if that makes a difference. Am I missing some framework or something? Did the initializer change?

Comment: What's wrong with `NumberFormatter`?

Comment: don't forget to `import Foundation`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should be working correctly. Can you please try the following:

```
import Foundation

let firstString = String(format: "%2.4f", arguments: [3.14159262])
print(firstString)
let secondString = String(format: "%2.4f", 3.14159262)
print(secondString)
```

I have this code running fine in a playground using Swift 5.

Removing the Foundation import gives the same error you described in your question.

Comment: Yeah, I was missing Foundation. Thanks! I'm new to all this, haven't had to use anything from Foundation yet